# Is there a way to configure GCP regions in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-platform, regions

Google Cloud Platform has various regions for hosting their services, e.g. West Europe 2 for London based services.

However, with Firebase, there seems to be no way to configure where content is hosted. Even if integrated with a GCP project (via Blaze plan) there doesn't seem to be a way to configure a region for storage or functions other than the default US Central region.

1) Is there possibly a way to configure which region Firebase is hosted in?

2) Does the current US-centric hosting affect performance from locations such as the UK? For example, if someone navigates to my web app in London, is the web page calling GCP cloud functions based in the US, which in turn is fetching data located in, for example, London?

Answer (score 3):

Firebase consists of quite a few products. Unfortunately not all of them allow you to select the region.

Specifically for Cloud Storage, you can add your own buckets to Firebase by clicking in the overflow menu in the [Storage panel of the Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/storage) and choosing <kbd>Add bucket</kbd>. These additional buckets can be in any zone.

For Cloud Functions, is now possible to specify the region. See my answer here: [firebase deploy to custom region (eu-central1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569595/firebase-deploy-to-custom-region-eu-central1) and [this post on the firebase-talk mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/Md1SijDDYsA/EvIptkRbBQAJ).

Your question on performance depends largely on the type of function you're looking to use. There is no cookie cutter answer.

Comment: what is the new update ? directly we can't move us central to asia south GCP in firebase console?