# Firebase cloud function onCall not working after changing region

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I built few cloud functions like this one:

```
const addRoom = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
```

It works perfectly but I wanted to change region to europe-west. I followed this stackoverflow: [firebase deploy to custom region (eu-central1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569595/firebase-deploy-to-custom-region-eu-central1)

```
const addRoom = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onCall((data, context) => {
```

It looks working fine for all functions (triggers) **except onCall functions**. I got this error when calling addRoom function on client side :

```
firebase.functions().httpsCallable("addRoom")(data)
```

> Access to fetch at
>   'https://us-central1-myproject.cloudfunctions.net/addRoom' from origin
>   'http://localhost:4200/new-room' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
>   Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

At this moment I use default region for onCall functions but is there a way to correct that or is that an error from firebase ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On the client side, you should specify the desired region at initialization and call the function as follows:

```
var functions = firebase.app().functions('europe-west1');

....

functions.httpsCallable("addRoom")(data)
```

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#http_and_client_callable_functions

Comment: Is there an update regarding this practice, as I am currently initializing cloud functions in web v9 like this
export const functions = getFunctions(app);

Comment: @CondorW export const functions = getFunctions(app, "europe-west1");

Answer (score 0):

for angular application you should provide the region like this in app module

```
providers: [
    { provide: REGION, useValue: 'europe-west3' }
]
```

and call the function like this:

```
constructor(private aff: AngularFireFunctions) {}

sendMail(data: { ... }): Promise<any> {
    return this.aff.httpsCallable('function_name')(data).pipe(first()).toPromise()
}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution for a modern implementation with `@angular/fire`