# How to set the region for all firebase cloud functions at once?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

We need to change the location for all of our cloud functions from `'us-central1'` to `('us-central1', 'europe-west1')`

We can go through every function manually and add `.region('us-central1', 'europe-west1')` but I wondered if there is a possibility to set the region globally to multiple regions for all cloud functions at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the region for all your firebase cloud functions as mentioned in the [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62056838/15774176) and You can also refer to the [documentation1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#modify-region) and [documentation2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#best_practices_for_changing_region) where a brief explanation provided towards the best practice for changing the firebase Cloud functions as stated:

> ```
> // before
> const functions = require('firebase-functions');
>
> exports.webhook = functions
>     .https.onRequest((req, res) => {
>             res.send("Hello");
>     });
>
> // after
> const functions = require('firebase-functions');
>
> exports.webhookAsia = functions
>     .region('asia-northeast1')
>     .https.onRequest((req, res) => {
>             res.send("Hello");
>     });
> ```

Comment: @CaitlynCodr Posted an answer, Is it helpful?