# Firebase Python Function: Configuration

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-functions

In TypeScript/Javascript it was possible to configure the Firebase function inline in code like so

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export const fooFunction = functions
  .runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 60,
    memory: "512MB",
  })
  .region("us-central1")
  .https.onCall((data, context) => {
     // function body
});
```

What's the equivalent in Python?

```
from firebase_functions import https_fn

@https_fn.on_call()
def foo_function(req: https_fn.CallableRequest) -> https_fn.Response:
   # function body
```

How do I set **region**, **timeout**, and **memory** (RAM)?

Comment: Have you seen the API documentation for [on_call](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/python/firebase_functions.https_fn#firebase_functions.https_fn.on_call) and the [HttpsOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/python/firebase_functions.options#firebase_functions.options.HttpsOptions) it receives?

Comment: Will try it and post a working example! Did not notice - thanks

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent in Python would look like this:

```py
from firebase_functions import https_fn
from firebase_admin import initialize_app

initialize_app()


@https_fn.on_call(region="europe-west3", memory=512, timeout_sec=90)
def example(req: https_fn.CallableRequest) -> Any:
    return "Hello world!"
```

`on_call()` and `on_request()` can receive `**kwargs` ([documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/python/firebase_functions.https_fn#functions)), the possible parameters and their names are analog to [`HttpsOptions`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/python/firebase_functions.options#httpsoptions).